# Celery sync data between sub processes

Tags: python, celery, threadpool, rate-limiting, apscheduler

I have a python application that includes flask, apscheduler, and Celery.   The scheduler creates tasks for celery workers to compute.   The issue is that the celery workers are polling APIs that are rate limited.   So in my attempt to keep track of the url, access key, and time to not get rate limited by the API,  I created a global class in the parent process.   But as I soon found out,  even though it is a global object,  it is only a copy that the workers update.

So I am now wondering what I can do?   I want something fast, thus why I chose to use in memory cache vs DB fetches and updates.    As of writing this I have a pool of 5 worker threads that will be making requests.

Any opinions or suggestions are welcome how I can keep track of api requests that the workers are making.

As mentioned above, I have tried creating a in memory object to keep track of the requests the child workers are making.   Celery is the application where this is taking place

******************** example code *****************************

```
from .celery import app, Task
import requests
import time

### scripts ###
from APIClassimport APIClass
from RateLimits import ratelimits
from makeRequests import pollAPI


class taskBase(Task):
  def on_failure(self, *args, **kwargs):
    pass

##############################################
################### TASKS ####################
##############################################

ratelimits = ratelimits()

@app.task(base=taskBase, bind=True)
def getMoreData(self, api_keys, team):
  global ratelimits
  ## do stuff

@app.task(base=taskBase, bind=True)
def getData(self, api_keys):
  global ratelimits
  a = APIClass(api_key=api_keys, ratelimits=ratelimits) #this class will set the time in ratelimits
  pollAPI(apis=a).run() 
  print({'status':'done'})
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @СергейКох updated with some example code